Improving data prediction using ARIMA model
I am experiencing a problem related to data prediction using stock prices for training and value prediction. When running the API  the results gotten from the model has relatively low accuracy even after implementing stationarity checks and differencing of the data. the model for stock prices with relatively low deviation before differencing gives rather large changes of a short time period and for those with larger deviation acquire low changes in prices.
What can  be the cause of this and how can I enhance the model.
the model uses ARIMA method to carry out the prediction.
